# Why is the braced-init-list not supported in an aggregate deduction but brace elision is supported?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Why is the braced-init-list not supported in an aggregate deduction but brace elision is supported?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
struct Test{
    T t[2];
};
int main(){
  Test t{{1,2}};  // #1
  // Test t1{1,2} // #2
}
```

`#1` is [rejected](https://godbolt.org/z/3493c1318) by GCC while `#2` would be accepted by GCC.

According to [over.match.class.deduct#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1)

> In addition, if C is defined and its definition satisfies the conditions for an aggregate class ([dcl.init.aggr]) with the assumption that any dependent base class has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes, and the initializer is a non-empty braced-init-list or parenthesized expression-list, and there are no deduction-guides for C, the set contains an additional function template, called the aggregate deduction candidate, defined as follows.  Let X<sub>1</sub>,...,X<sub>N</sub> be the elements of the initializer-list or designated-initializer-list of the braced-init-list, or of the expression-list. For each X<sub>i</sub>, let e<sub>i</sub> be the corresponding aggregate element of C or of one of its (possibly recursive) subaggregates that would be initialized by X<sub>i</sub>  if
>
> > - [1.5] brace elision is not considered for any aggregate element that has a dependent non-array type or an array type with a value-dependent bound, and
> > - [1.6] each non-trailing aggregate element that is a pack expansion is assumed to correspond to no elements of the initializer list, and
> > - [1.7] a trailing aggregate element that is a pack expansion is assumed to correspond to all remaining elements of the initializer list (if any).

> If there is no such aggregate element e<sub>i</sub> for any X<sub>i</sub>, the aggregate deduction candidate is not added to the set. The aggregate deduction candidate is derived as above from a hypothetical constructor C(T<sub>1</sub>,...,T<sub>n</sub>)
>
> > - if e<sub>i</sub> is of array type and x<sub>i</sub> is a braced-init-list or string-literal, T<sub>i</sub> is an rvalue reference to the declared type of e<sub>i</sub>

In my example, the x<sub>1</sub> is a braced-init-list(`{1,2}`) and the type of e<sub>1</sub> is of array type T[2], hence the Constructor should be the form `C(T(&&)[2])` and the template argument can be deduced for `T(&&)[2]` from `{1,2}` as per [temp.deduct.call#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#1)

Why is the above example rejected by GCC? GCC whereas accepts the brace elision way? How to interpret this example? Is that considered the bug of GCC or something that I misunderstand?

---

Another issue I think it's weird is that if X<sub>i</sub> is a braced-init-list that should have been used to initialize the subaggregate, if bullet [1.5] is true, then X<sub>i</sub> will be used to initialize the element of the subaggregate. What does it mean?

#### UPDATE

After digging in further in [p2082r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2082r1.pdf). From its context, it seems that the wording **aggregate element** means an element of aggregate type instead of the aggregate's element. IIUC, if the bullet [1.5], [1.6], [1.7] is satisfied, e<sub>i</sub> will be the aggregate element. However, if these bullets are all not conformed, what will the e<sub>i</sub> be? It seems under-specified here.

Comment: clang rejects both and MSVC accepts both https://godbolt.org/z/brWM388zc so the 3 main compilers all give 3 different results. Nice.

Comment: @bolov I didn't feel it's weird that Clang rejects this example since Clang does not completely support c++20. Hence, I didn't mention Clang in my question.

Comment: [This GCC test](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/testsuite/g%2B%2B.dg/cpp2a/class-deduction-aggr4.C) from their testsuite contains almost the same code, except that the array size is also a template parameter - and in that case it compiles successfully.

Comment: @interjay Array type with value-dependent bound is another [case](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/testsuite/g%2B%2B.dg/cpp2a/class-deduction-aggr4.C#L11) that I want to talk about. I don't know whether bullet [1.5] is considered true? if it is true, then `ei` will the element of the array, where the array is the subaggregate of C. It seems a bit obscure.

Comment: @MarkusLenger Clang does not completely compatible with c++20. I used the latest GCC to test such a code. As well as these compilers in the link in the first comment above can also compile this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in GCC up to version 11.2, and fixed in GCC 11.3. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101344 for detailed explanation what caused this bug.

Even earlier versions of GCC can compile similar and even more difficult case `A` (as was mentioned in the comments to the question):

```
template<typename T, int N>
struct A { T t[N]; };

template<typename T>
struct B { T t[2]; };

int main()
{
   [[maybe_unused]] A a{{1, 2}}; //ok in GCC
   [[maybe_unused]] B b{{1, 2}}; //ok in GCC >= 11.3
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4rcYj6fah

Comment: I think GCC is right, please see the answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/68256261/11796722

Answer (score 2):

Digging in further in [P2082r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2082r1.pdf), I think GCC is right on this example. Since the subaggregate `T t[2]` of `Test` has an array of the non-dependent value bound, hence the corresponding e<sub>0</sub> and e<sub>1</sub> is `t0`,`t1`, respectively. Hence the derived guide is `template<typename T> Test(T, T)`.

When this guide is used as a constructor for the hypothetical class type to participate in overload resolution, [over.match.list] is applied here since the initializer is `{{1,2}}`, since there is no initializer-list constructor, the elements of the initializer-list are used as the arguments here, as aforementioned, the candidate `template<typename T> Test(T, T)` has two parameters but only one argument(`{1,2}`) supplies, hence the overload resolution is a failure, hence the program is ill-formed.

However, I still think the rule is not clear here and should be improved to make the meaning more explicit.